# Does deleting multiple rows in one statement reduce the size of the binlog

Tags: mysql, binlog

I need to remove a large amount of data, but need to do so without overwhelming the amount of data in the binlog.  From the binlog's perspective are the following 2 equivalent?

```
delete from table sample where id in (1, 2,3)
```

and

```
delete from table sample where id = 1; 
delete from table sample where id = 2;
delete from table sample where id = 3;
```

Comment: What version of MySQL?  What are you using the binlog for?  What is the value of `binlog_format`?

Comment: Also what is the value of [binlog_row_image](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_row_image) and [binlog_row_metadata](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_row_metadata)? You could set these to MINIMAL.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'binlog%';`

Answer (score 3):

- First, I'll say that the answer is "it depends".  With `binlog_format = "STATEMENT"`, the statements are put in the binlog; hence the second format is bigger.
- With "ROW" format, information about *each* row is put in the binlog.  So, the number of bytes going into the binlog is the same either way.  However, there is likely to be some overhead on each statement.  So again, I *think* the second format will be at least slightly bigger.
- Are the statement(s) inside a "transaction"?  If not, then each *statement* is a separate transaction, which does have some overhead in the binlog.  Furthermore, if the binlog is being used for replication, the ACID semantics are different.
- A million-row `DELETE` is very heavyweight when executed -- it must save all the old rows, delete them, then toss the saved copies if you actually `COMMIT` (versus `ROLLBACK`).  My point is that there are other issues you *may* need to consider in choosing between the two approaches.  I like to delete no more than 1000 rows at a time.
- If you have `expire...` set, the binlogs will be 'rotated' periodically, so it mostly does not matter how bulky they are.

What is your concern?  Maybe I left out something.